# How to make playbook pick the system user automatically

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy files to multiple environments using a single ansible playbook but the user name on those environments is different.

for eg. lets say I want to run my playbook on two remote servers

serverA's file target location is /home/jason/{{ filename }}

serverB's file target location is /home/mary/{{ filename }}

and here is my playbook:

```
- name: copy config files
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  tasks:
    - name: copy latest version files
      copy: src=version.txt dest=/home/jason/version.txt
```

Currently I have /home/jason hardcoded, wondering if the playbooks can handle the situation where if the user on the target server is "jason" then pick the file target location as /home/jason else if the user is "mary" then use /home/mary

Answer (score 0):

There is `ansible_user_dir` fact available, so:

```
- name: copy latest version files
  copy:
    src: version.txt
    dest: "{{ ansible_user_dir }}/version.txt"
```